# Making a Choice on Migrating Oracle PL/SQL to Java Classes / EJB

Tags: java, oracle, plsql, ejb

Wondering what could be decision points/factor in deciding on the option of converting the PLSQL in the Java Class/EJB's.

There is sizable amount of business logic implemented into the PLSQL where the front end was PowerBuilder.

Now to make the application web-enabled, application is being migrated to Java/J2EE with Struts Framework.

Is is  necessary to migrate the PLSQL too along with the user interface, specially when the RDBMS continues to be on Oracle and there is expertise available on PL/SQL.

What factors to take into consideration in making a choice?

Comment: There are two points of view which are virtually ideological: business rules in the middle tier or business rules in the database. There are no clear right or wrong answers, it really depends on the specific situation.  But as this is a topic which can only generated a debate (and an old one at that) I am voting to close this question as Not Constructive.

Answer (score 4):

> "Is is necessary to migrate the PLSQL too along with the user
>   interface , specially when the RDBMS continues to be on Oracle and
>   there is expertise available on PLSQL."

Not only is it not necessary it is completely unadvisable.

You have a PL/SQL API which (presumably) works.  You have people who understand it and have the skills to maintain it.  Why would you want to move that into Java for *no discernable business benefit*.

You are going to have enough fun just writing the front end in Java.  Get that working first before you make any decisions regarding other layers of the application.

One final thought: you have PL/SQL developers: why not develop a web front end in [Apex](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex/overview/index.html) instead?

Comment: +1 excellent, and so true!  I've seen plenty of Java devs who have absolutely no business mucking with the database, let alone convert a working set of pl/sql packages

Comment: @APC  I find your answer amusing as it suits your bio and job security..  cannot expect a different perspective from database developer. I totally understand your concern.  But this comment is in 2020.. I know 8 years after your answer. your answer is no more contemporary.  Now a days , ORM and frameworks are very much needed.  Instead of relying on only one particular DB like oracle ,it is always better to move business logic in stored procedures to something like java..so tomorrow , i can switch from oracle to any other database easily,  Given postgresql is opensource..save the license cost.

Comment: @Stunner - How often do organisations move their applications from one database product to another? Almost never. Why? Because RDBMSes are massive piles of **state**. Yes this makes databases "less agile", whatever that means, but it also makes shifting data hard work, expensive and risky. But the payoff from statefulness  is that our data is uncorrupted, highly available and easily accessible using standard industry tools. I am not here to defend Oracle's licensing fees, they are indefensible. But if we've bought Oracle the way to get the best ROI is to use **everything we've paid for**.

Comment: @stunner - BTW the first time I had this argument was in 2001/2 with some Java architect who wanted to move all our business logic into EJBs. Which would have been EJB 1.2 or something, not the lightweight EJB 3 protocol from a couple of years later (and what a giveaway is the need for a more lightweight implementation). That database is  still part of the organisation's business process. When was the last time you wrote anything an EJB?

Comment: EJB is dead. Agreed. Migrating from one framework to another will take time and effort  but it should be worth compared to the cost of license of the DB.  I know a lot of banks which are migrating from Oracle to opensource DB's like MariaDB and PostgreSQL for their core payments. Opensource  will be the new norm and Organizations will shift accordingly.

Comment: I don't want to invoke a "trigger" on DB.  I am rather happy to write a listener which is taken care at application server end.  Maybe this discussion is like choosing between coffee and tea.. Matter of choice :)

Answer (score 1):

If you can isolate the PL/SQL behind a proper domain model it might not be an issue, but you will be unlikely to be able to leverage modern ORM technologies like Hibernate or TopLink if you have a lot of legacy business logic in PL/SQL.

Our situation where I work is that we have a lot of business logic, implemented very badly, in PL/SQL - we have a special term for it - 'Magical SQL'.  Because we do not have as many Oracle resources as we would like any changes to legacy business logic take a long time.  We are trying to migrate logic into the Java layer as we go along, purely to make our system more maintainable and agile.

Short answer, it's not necessary but it may be wise (in my opinion) - edited to amend to state that it obviously depends on the situation.

Comment: You can prove anything with "badly implemented".  How many middle tiers have I come across where a shockingly implemented ORM retrieves gobs of data on a RBAR basis because the developers didn't understand the importance of set-based operations?  Or how to filter queries in the database? etc etc.

Comment: @APC I'm a firm believer in RDBMS, but in our particular case it has been seriously abused and we are sitting with a maintenance nightmare because of it.  Prior systems I've worked on have contained very well-written, consistent and isolated DB layers which we could happily interface against; that was great.  Sometimes, however, extracting it to the middle tier is the lesser of two weevils.  I guess what I'm trying to say is that it really is instance dependant.

Comment: Your situation is apparently quite different from the OP's.  So advising them on the basis of your experience iswrong.  And that's why I've voted to close this question as Not Constructive

Comment: Although you're saying the PL\SQL implementation is very bad because you don't have many Oracle people how do you know you're not creating an equally bad interface in Java?? We've just come across some code for an old website that basically said `select random_number between 0 and 9`. Why? It was written long ago by someone who didn't have a clue about Oracle and/or the data. Wherever you develop your logic you need people who know the data AND who know how to interface use the database.

Comment: The only thing less constructive than a Not Constructive question, is a closed Not Constructive question.